# How to properly setup a sw-entity-multi-select field for products and save them to your extension

Tags: vue.js, shopware

i'm completely new to shopware, not very familiar with javascript and struggling with the **sw-entity-multi-select field**.

**I want to save the selected Items to my extension**, but i havn't find an easy solution for that, instead i'm doing some awful Object.assign stuff, so i can save at least something.

Question 1: How can i save properly selections to my extension?

Question 2: How can i properly display the saved selections

Here is my html.twig:

```
{% block sw_product_detail_attribute_sets %}
    {% parent() %}
    <div v-if="!isLoading && parentProduct && product">
        <sw-card :title="$tc('sw-product.detail.requiredProductsCardLabel')"
                :isLoading="isLoading">

            <sw-inherit-wrapper
                v-if="!isLoading"
                v-model="RPExtension"
                :has-parent="!!parentProduct.id"
                :inherited-value="parentRPExtension"
            > 
                <template #content="{ isInherited }">
                <sw-entity-multi-select
                    v-if="!isLoading"
                    entity="product"
                    :key="isInherited"
                    :entity-collection="products"
                    @change="setProducts"
                    :placeholder="$tc('sw-product.detail.requiredProductsPlaceholder')">
                </sw-entity-multi-select>
            </sw-inherit-wrapper>

        </sw-card>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And also the index.js for the html.twig:

```
import template from './sw-product-detail-requiredProducts.html.twig';

const { Component, Context } = Shopware;
const { mapState, mapGetters } = Component.getComponentHelper();
const { EntityCollection, Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.override('sw-product-detail-base', {
    template,

    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],

    data() {
      return {
        products: null,
      };
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState('swProductDetail', [
            'product',
            'parentProduct',
        ]),

        ...mapGetters('swProductDetail', [
            'isLoading',
        ]),

        productRepository() {
          console.log('productRepository');
          return this.repositoryFactory.create('product');

        },

        requiredProductsRepository() {
          return this.repositoryFactory.create('product_preconditions')
        },

      productContext() {
        return { ...Shopware.Context.api, inheritance: true };
    },

      RPExtension: {
          get: function() {
              if (this.product && this.product.extensions && this.product.extensions['requiredProducts']) {
                  return (
                      this.product.extensions['requiredProducts']['productPrecondition']
                  );
              }

              return null;
          },
          set: function(value) {
              this.$set(this.product.extensions['requiredProducts'], 'productPrecondition', value ?? null);
          }
      },

      parentRPExtension() {
          if (this.parentProduct && this.parentProduct.extensions && this.parentProduct.extensions['requiredProducts']) {
              return (
                  this.product.extensions['requiredProducts']['productPrecondition']
              );
          }

          return null;
      },
    },

    created() {
      this.createdComponent();
    }, 
    
    methods: {
      createdComponent() {
        this.products = new EntityCollection(
          this.productRepository.route,
          this.productRepository.entityName,
          Shopware.Context.api,
        );
      },

      setProducts(selectedProducts) {
        this.products = selectedProducts;
        this.products.forEach((selectedProduct) => {
          const precondition = this.createProductPreconditionEntity(selectedProduct);
          this.product.extensions.requiredProducts.push(precondition);
        });
      },

      createProductPreconditionEntity(selectedProduct) {
          const productPreconditions = this.requiredProductsRepository.create(Context.api);
          Object.assign(productPreconditions, {
              productId: this.product.id,
              productPrecondition: selectedProduct.id,
              directPrecondition: false
          });

          return productPreconditions;
      },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you basically explain what you are trying to do?
What property you trying to save? What should it do? You need it in your product data?

Guess the simplest way is to do it with custom fields. So you don't need to create the admin presentation in vuejs if you not familiar with.